# mri_21 is not a valid platform

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

Hi i switched my Ruby on Rails development platform from Windows 7 to Linux (Debian), I copied entire app directory to Linux and run `bundle install`and the command was successful. Than i run `rake db:migrate` and it quit with following error:

```
`mri_21` is not a valid platform. The available options are: [:ruby, :ruby_18, :ruby_19, :mri, :mri_18, :mri_19, :rbx, :jruby, :mswin, :mingw, :mingw_18, :mingw_19]
```

Than i Googled for the error and found [this](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails_apps_composer/issues/297), i followed the suggested steps, i.e.:

```
gem update bundler
```

above command output:

```
Updating installed gems
Nothing to update
```

Than: `bundle install` and this was also successful.
But still getting same error on `rake db:migrate`

my ruby version: `ruby 1.9.3p194`
unable to get rails version by `rails -v` getting the same mri_21 error but in my app's Gemfile i have `gem 'rails', '4.1.5'`

EDIT: But when i tried `bundle exec rake db:migrate` it was successful. and than i run `bundle exec rails s` and app running successfully :

```
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 4.1.5 application starting in development on 0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
>> Thin web server (v1.3.1 codename Triple Espresso)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
```

Now my question is, how to get rid of this `bundle exec` every time, and what's going on with this.

Comment: did you try `bundle exec rake db:migrate`

Comment: yes i tried, just after asking this question and its working.

Comment: you should have all the gem binaries in the PATH variable before that are specified to wrong versions of rails, and gems, then you be able to avoid the `bundle exec`

Answer (score 0):

Since `bundle exec` just fixes the `PATH`, and `GEM_PATH` variables, you should have all the gem binaries in the `PATH` variable before that are specified to wrong versions of rails, and gems. Also set `GEM_PATH` properly. So you be able to avoid the `bundle exec` call. All the values you are able to know with calls:

```
 $ bundle exec echo GEM_HOME=$GEM_HOME\; GEM_PATH=$GEM_PATH\; PATH=$PATH
 GEM_HOME=/home/malo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4; GEM_PATH=/home/malo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4:/home/malo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@global; PATH=/home/malo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/bin:/home/malo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@global/bin:/home/malo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/bin:/home/malo/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/home/malo/.rbenv/bin:/home/malo/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/games:/usr/lib/qt4/bin
```